# vertical adjustment in mathmode

Tags: math-mode

I created the symbol `${}_{\ulcorner\!\urcorner}$` by typing ulcorner followed by urcorner with the appropriate spacing, and forcing it down by placing it into a subscript. However, this made the symbol smaller than I wanted it to be. I spent a while searching this site for clues how I might move things down in mathmode but didn't find anything. What would be the simplest way of getting this symbol larger but still aligned at the same level with the letters rather than a bit above them?

Comment: perhaps `\raisebox{-2pt}{$\ulcorner\!\urcorner$}` ?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is what you're looking for:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,calc}

\newcommand{\foo}{%
  \text{\raisebox{\heightof{$\lrcorner$}}{\raisebox{-\height}{$\ulcorner\!\urcorner$}}}%
}

\begin{document}

$\foo xx_{\foo}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, somehow I overlooked the raisebox function, as pointed out by @StevenB.Segletes.